# Getting the intersection points of 2 circles

Tags: c#, geometry, intersection

I need to be able to calculate the intersection points between 2 circles. I know for sure that there will always be 2 intersection points. Not 1, not 0, not infinite, always 2. Here is a diagram of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Here is my current attempt:

```
public static List<Vector2> intersect(Vector3 c1, Vector3 c2, float rad1, float rad2)
{
    List<Vector2> rLp = new List<Vector2>();
    float d = Vector2.Distance(c1, c2);

    if (d > (rad1 + rad2))
        return rLp;
    else if (d == 0 && rad1 == rad2)
        return rLp;
    else if ((d + Mathf.Min(rad1, rad2)) < Mathf.Max(rad1, rad2))
        return rLp;
    else
    {
        float a = (rad1 * rad1 - rad2 * rad2 + d * d) / (2 * d);
        float h = Mathf.Sqrt(rad1 * rad1 - a * a);

        Vector2 p2 = new Vector2((float)(c1.x + (a * (c2.x - c1.x)) / d), (float)(c1.y + (a * c2.y - c1.y) / d));

        Vector2 i1 = new Vector2((float)(p2.x + (h * (c2.y - c1.y)) / d), (float)(p2.y - (h * (c2.x - c1.x)) / d));
        Vector2 i2 = new Vector2((float)(p2.x - (h * (c2.y - c1.y)) / d), (float)(p2.y + (h * (c2.x - c1.x)) / d));

        if (d == (rad1 + rad2))
            rLp.Add(i1);
        else
        {
            rLp.Add(i1);
            rLp.Add(i2);
        }

        return rLp;
    }
}
```

It gives me the following result:

[image]

As you can see, the white squares representing the intercepting points between the two circles are in the wrong place. I could really use some help in this area. Can anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: *Intersection* is what you would Google for; http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/09/determine-where-two-circles-intersect-in-c/

Comment: I've already been on that page, I'm almost certain you'll find the code on that page on my sample.cs

Comment: Post what you tried in the question, not some external site. Also, what math did you try to use? This is high-school geometry

Comment: I always test before posting a link and that project lets you draw 2 circles then highlights the intersection points via FindCircleCircleIntersections() - i.e. your A1 & A2 data points

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: As requested I've posted the code I've used so far

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: It sounds like you're not sure about the maths. Check your maths first, then the code.

Comment: This is what I mean:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20794300/Circle%20Circle/Untitled-1.png

Comment: The link cited by @AlexK. has changed. The material can now be found at http://csharphelper.com/howtos/howto_circle_circle_intersection.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copy&Paste of math-code almost always goes wrong for me (e.g. flipped signes in definitions, etc). Debugging such code from other people is just pure horror (debugging my own is hard enough when it goes deeper into math). You should try to do the calculations on your own and translate it into code. If it goes wrong, you can step trough it with a debugger and cross-check with a pocket calculator.

You realy should try on your own. Grab a sheet of paper and get the math right. But here is the approach I would use:

```
private void intersectionTwoCircles(double c1x, double c1y, double r1, double c2x, double c2y, double r2,
        out double a1x, out double a1y, out double a2x, out double a2y)
    {
        /* error handling is missing complettely - left as an exercise 

              A1
             /| \
         r1 / |  \ r2
           /  |   \
          /   |h   \
         /g1  |     \          (g1 means angle gamma1)
        C1----P-----C2
           d1   d2
        */
        double dx = c1x - c2x;
        double dy = c1y - c2y;
        double d = Math.Sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy); // d = |C1-C2|
        double gamma1 = Math.Acos((r2*r2 + d*d - r1*r1)/(2*r2*d)); // law of cosines
        double d1 = r1*Math.Cos(gamma1); // basic math in right triangle
        double h = r1*Math.Sin(gamma1);
        double px = c1x + (c2x - c1x) / d*d1;
        double py = c1y + (c2y - c1y) / d*d1;
        // (-dy, dx)/d is (C2-C1) normalized and rotated by 90 degrees
        a1x = px + (-dy)/d*h;      
        a1y = py + (+dx) / d * h;
        a2x = px - (-dy) / d * h;
        a2y = py - (+dx) / d * h;
    }
```

---

update after code provided:

Your approach is very similar to mine( `a=r1 cos(gamma_1)` and `h=r1 sin(gamma_1)`). You just avoid to calculate `gamma` directly. It's faster (just one `sqrt` instead of `cos`, `sin` and `acos`). But I think, mine is a bit more readable ;) Think about overloading the operands of your vector class (+, -, *, ...) ... your code will become much easier to read.

And I think I've found your error ....

```
// before
Vector2 p2 = new Vector2((float)(c1.x + (a * (c2.x - c1.x)) / d), (float)(c1.y + (a * c2.y - c1.y) / d));

// after
Vector2 p2 = new Vector2((float)(c1.x + (a * (c2.x - c1.x)) / d), (float)(c1.y + a * (c2.y - c1.y) / d));
```

Comment: Those are the most beautiful code comments I've ever seen.  Seriously, brings a tear to my eye.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: I (try to) never comment but make the code obvious without them. But when it goes it to math, my comment:code-ratio sometimes approaches 1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for an implementation using PointF instead of discrete coordinates, I adapted the solution from the [link](http://csharphelper.com/howtos/howto_circle_circle_intersection.html) mentioned by Alex K five years ago to produce the following. Although it's not optimized for a known, 2-point case as described by the OP, it works and accommodates circles that intersect in one, two, or no points.

```cs
using System.Drawing;
using static System.Math;

public static class CircleIntersections {

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the intersections of two circles
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="center1">The first circle's center</param>
    /// <param name="center2">The second circle's center</param>
    /// <param name="radius1">The first circle's radius</param>
    /// <param name="radius2">The second circle's radius. If omitted, assumed to equal the first circle's radius</param>
    /// <returns>An array of intersection points. May have zero, one, or two values</returns>
    /// <remarks>Adapted from http://csharphelper.com/howtos/howto_circle_circle_intersection.html</remarks>
    public static PointF[] GetCircleIntersections(PointF center1, PointF center2, double radius1, double? radius2 = null) {

        var (r1, r2) = (radius1, radius2 ?? radius1);
        (double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) = (center1.X, center1.Y, center2.X, center2.Y);
        // d = distance from center1 to center2
        double d = Sqrt(Pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Pow(y1 - y2, 2));
        // Return an empty array if there are no intersections
        if (!(Abs(r1 - r2) <= d && d <= r1 + r2)) { return new PointF[0]; }

        // Intersections i1 and possibly i2 exist
        var dsq = d * d;
        var (r1sq, r2sq) = (r1 * r1, r2 * r2);
        var r1sq_r2sq = r1sq - r2sq;
        var a = r1sq_r2sq / (2 * dsq);
        var c = Sqrt(2 * (r1sq + r2sq) / dsq - (r1sq_r2sq * r1sq_r2sq) / (dsq * dsq) - 1);

        var fx = (x1 + x2) / 2 + a * (x2 - x1);
        var gx = c * (y2 - y1) / 2;

        var fy = (y1 + y2) / 2 + a * (y2 - y1);
        var gy = c * (x1 - x2) / 2;

        var i1 = new PointF((float)(fx + gx), (float)(fy + gy));
        var i2 = new PointF((float)(fx - gx), (float)(fy - gy));

        return i1 == i2 ? new PointF[] { i1 } : new PointF[] { i1, i2 };
    }
}
```